# Which software is best to edit content from brochures, sales sheets etc. that were created by contracted graphic designers?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, adobe-photoshop-elements

I am a business owner that is starting to hire people online to create sales sheets, brochures, etc. I understand most designers will use Adobe Illustrator, however without any training it can be difficult software to use. If I am looking to make minor edits to the designs others create (such as change some text or change a picture) will I be able to do that with a software such as photoshop elements? I am looking for the best option that isn't too expensive, and easy enough to use for someone without any graphic design training.

Comment: usually the same software used to create the files. But I'd go with the advices below and hire a designer for a small fee, you'd get better results and less headaches.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Not sure who gave you that information, but Adobe Illustrator isn't usually used for brochure layout. The industry standard software for page layout is Adobe InDesign.

Comment: Welcome to **GDSE** - take a look around [tour] at ***who*** and what this community is, and also look over [ask] and [answer] whilst you're here. One thing about your post as initially written is **unclear**: are you *initially* proposing a template-based workflow with your designers prior to their beginning work (I.E. you stipulate requiring post-production editable files, with relevant tolerances,  all necessary copyrights fully pre-purchased and contracted) or are you asking us to advise you on *modifying work* ***already delivered*** as *final*, which was designed using Adobe Illustrator?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do minor edits with a wrong tool. Fix electric wiring on your car with sticky tape, a broken pipe with bubble gum or put a nail on a wall using a shoe.

You also can pay one month of Illustrator just for minor changes without training... and not use it for anything else.

Or you can pay some **fair price** to someone to do minor changes for **a small fee**. That person has some training, not only on the usage of the software but also in which would be a feasible way to fix the problem and would have paid the software's monthly fee.

> I am a business owner.

I am sure you want your business to be respected because you want to do a good job in your area of expertise. We all do.

---

But I will assume that you need constant changes, let's say you are the owner of a coffee shop and you need to update prices on a regular basis...

Then you need to say that prior to the job to be done, as a requirement.

In that case, the designer could prepare the project on another software. Probably Word itself, or another free one like Inkscape or Scribus.

But talk to the designer with those requirements in mind... Prior to the execution of the job.

A project that has editing capabilities is different than a final product. You either pay for a brochure, or you pay for a "template" for a brochure.

Answer (score 1):

You are not expecting a little. You must at first negotiate and sign a written agreement that you can legally make edits and you get editable versions of the designs. Generally prepare to pay a premium to get that right and the original editable files.

You must use the same software as was used to the original designs,  anything else give unsure results. And for CMYK printed products the software must be CMYK print aware, do not expect any cheapware or freeware do it, if the design is made with Adobe's pro software.

Editing PDFs with Acrobat Pro sometimes works and sometimes not. PDFs must be prepared to be editable if you want to make succesful edits. Even in that case you very likely  have not enough control for large changes. But updating a price, name or image goes well.

I bet you do better by negotiating an agreement for maintenance ie. the original designer makes the wanted new versions with predictable cost and time schedule for some time, say 3 years and then you get the editable versions for a predetermined price.

Finally: If you are going to publish something you have made, you must have the right to use every graphical piece in that design (drawings, fonts, texts, photos). Your original designer maybe have himself no right to sell nor give for free everything to you, for ex. fonts and 3rd party images must be repurchased from the original supplier.

Answer (score 1):

**How or even *if* you can edit any particular file depends upon exactly the edits you want to make and how the original file was set up.**

Some files may be relatively easy to make something like a small text change, **if** you have a PDF with "live" text and in some cases the *font* used in ther piece.

On the other hand, editing things like a photograph would, in most cases, require the original application used.

In short, this is really a very broad topic and can't be answered effectively.

**Talk to the designer**. He/She may be willing to provide some options. There are *many* things considered when a design is created. Especially if it is a print design. At times, it's not wise to edit things if you don't fully understand the *technical requirements* needed for a particular reproduction method. But.. I don't mean to imply it's "rocket science".

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Acrobat DC can manipulate PDFs to a large degree. 
Just a note: Be careful with versioning of files if you're editing post-export. If you've made changes that aren't in the original design file then they will be exported from your designer with those again the next time.